# A Game Exit Menu

Tags: vbscript, hta

I need some help with a quick question.I have a HTA Application that is the menu for a game I am making, here is the problem, I have a exit button, but when you click it, it just closes the program, but what I want is to make it so when you click the exit button, a  VBS dialog box pops up and asks, "Are you sure you want to exit the game?", with yes or no buttons, can anyone help me?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the procedure called by your exit button look like this:

```
Sub ExitHTA
  answer = MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo)
  If answer = vbYes Then self.close()
End Sub
```

If you want you can put the application name as the message box title like this:

```
<html>
<title>My Game</title>

<HTA:APPLICATION ID="oHTA"
  APPLICATIONNAME="My Game"
  ...
>

<script language="VBScript">
  ...

  Sub ExitHTA
    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo, oHTA.ApplicationName)
    If answer = vbYes Then self.close()
  End Sub
</script>

<body>
...
<input type="button" id="exitbtn" onClick="vbscript:ExitHTA" value="Exit">
...
</body>
```